# Testing for errors in dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I am doing a homework excercise that is working with dictionaries. The purpose was to create a program that has a dictionary with names and birthdays as their values. Its meant to ask for an input being what person they want to know the birthday of. I am attempting to add a 'feature' that if they input a name not in the dictionary, it will output a message something like 'Im sorry, that name is not reconized try again.'

I tried something below but it does not work.

```py
birthdays = {
    "Jeremy" : '3/28/01',
    "Jacob" : '6/30/01',
    "Colin" : '10/5/00',
    "Chris Evans" : '6/13/81',
    "Robert Downey Jr." : '4/4/65',
    "Ryan Reynolds" : '10/23/76',
}
def run_program():
    print("This is a program that will tell you the birthdays of some of my friends as long as some famous names!")
    print("We have the birthdays of: ")
    for key in birthdays:
        print(key)
    return_value = input("Whose birthday would you like to know?: ")
    for key in birthdays:
        if[return_value] not in birthdays[]:
            print("I'm sorry try again?")
            return_value = input("Whose birthday would you like to know?: ")
        else
            print(str(return_value.lower().capitalize())+ "'s birtday is: ")
            print(birthdays[return_value.lower().capitalize()])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_program()
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: its an SyntaxError on line 16 if[return_value] not in birthdays[]:

Comment: I guess it should be - `if return_value not in birthdays:`

Comment: The code also seems to be missing a colon after `else:`

Comment: Please run your example code and fix the syntax errors that Python will point out to you and if you still have questions after fixing the typos (or you have a specific question about what you need to fix), update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code. I guess your need is that till a match is found, you want to ask the question, so use `while` loop. When condition meets, you just break and comes out of the loop. Also, you had some error in searching for keys in the dictionary.

```
def run_program():
    print("This is a program that will tell you the birthdays of some of my friends as long as some famous names!")
    print("We have the birthdays of: ")
    for key in birthdays:
        print(key)
    return_value = input("Whose birthday would you like to know?: ")
    while True:
        if return_value not in birthdays.keys():
            print("I'm sorry try again?")
            return_value = input("Whose birthday would you like to know?: ")
        else:
            print(str(return_value.lower().capitalize())+ "'s birtday is: ")
            print(birthdays[return_value.lower().capitalize()])
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_program()
```

Comment: This one doesn't fix the behavior with the second input.  Also, it's usually considered good practice to post some explanation with your answers as opposed to just code, that way the person gets some understanding of how and why the program works, not just that it does.

Answer (score 0):

and welcome to StackOverflow!  One reason this isn't doing what you want is in line 16, you have

```
if[return_value] not in birthdays[]:
```

This is incorrect syntax for two reasons.  One, the variable name doesn't go in brackets when used to check like this.  Two, you don't put the brackets after the name of your dictionary unless you want to find a specific key in said dictionary.

So, that line should be changed to something more like

```
if return_value not in birthdays:
```

Also, if they enter a name that isn't in the dictionary, when it prompts them for another name it does nothing with the name.  Just ends the program with no output.  I can edit that in in a bit if you'd like, after you try and fix that part yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, birthday is a dictionary. If you try to access a key that is not present in the dictionary python will raise KeyError, so you can put a try/catch around your code and handle the missing key.

Beside this, your code has some little mistakes, but don't be afraid they are common when we're begging

In

```
    for key in birthdays:
        print(key)
```

You want print the birthdays keys so you need `birthdays.keys()` which return the list of keys in a dict, so

```
    for key in birthdays.keys():
        print(key)
```

After receiving a name you want to check if that name is in the birthdays dict. In python there is a convention to use EAFP (Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission). What this is telling us is that is more *pythonic* to use try/catch in place of if/else. In this case you can try to access the key and handle `KeyError` if it is not present, here it is how

```py
   ...
   while True:
       return_value = input("Whose birthday would you like to know?: ")
       try:
          print(f"{return_value.lower().capitalize()}'s birthday is {birthdays[return_value.lower().capitalize()]}")
          break
       except KeyError as e:
          print("I'm sorry try again?")
```

Regards